# Why is writing a file using NodeJS fs throwing exception 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

I'm using the NodeJS package `fs` to write a file to disk. Why would `writeFile()` throw a `No such file or directory` error when it's supposed to create the file if it doesn't exist?

My code:

```
import { promises as fsp } from 'fs';
await fsp.writeFile(filepath, readableStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If filepath contains certain invalid characters (in my case, a semicolon `:`), then it will throw this exception and fail to write the file.